# Determine if file is a folder or file Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to determine whether the I am looking at a folder or a file. I did the following approach. Rather then going to the if statement that checks if its a folder, it goes the the else. My question is: How do I determine if I am looking at a folder or a file?

```
<cfif structKeyExists(URL, 'method') and URL.method eq 'download'>
<cfset folder_name = URL.folder_id />
<cfset file_name = URL.name />

<cfif findNoCase('.dir', folder_name) >
    <a href="subfolder_files.cfm?method=download&path=#folder_name#&folder_id=#file_name#">hi</a>
<cfelse>
    <a href="process_file_page.cfm?method=download&folder_id=#file_name#&name=#URLEncodedFormat(Name)#"></a>
</cfif>
<cfabort>
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the literal values of those URL variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it's not recommended to send the folder path and file name via the query string. It might be possible for someone to poke around, find and download files in the system that aren't intended to be accessed. It's called a [path traversal attack.](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal)

Do the folder names contain the string `.dir`? Because that's the condition being checked. If they don't, then that's why it's always going to the `else` condition.

```
<cfif findNoCase('.dir', folder_name) >
```

Use `directoryExists()` against the folder path and `fileExists()` against the file name to see if either exist before attempting to request the file.

A better approach would be to save the file path and name in the DB, then request the file by ID in the query string. The file should also be stored outside of the web root so they are not in a publicly accessible folder and can't be accessed without being logged into the application. Once you can find the correct file, use `<cfcontent>` to download the file to the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Adrain J. Moreno. I was able to determine how to do it with your help

Comment: @Adrain J. Moreno: I do  have a question regarding shortcuts: How can I show what the shortcut is when the user clicks to display the page?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "shortcut".

Comment: J Moreno: I mean a desktop shortcut to a site, folder, etc.